# implementing SSO across subdomains in joomla

Tags: joomla, joomla2.5, single-sign-on, session-cookies

First of all i have done numerous reading on session cookies, joomla sessions and logins but i don't seem to find the solution or at-least dont understand how it works.

I have three joomla websites with one of them being the main domain and the rest subdomains.

I want to be able to automatically logged in to my subdomains when i login to my main domain.

I have done the following so far,

All three websites share user info tables (users, groups, access levels).
They share the same secret value.
The cookie domain in all three websites is .domain.com.

but when i login to my main site i dont seem to be logged in to the subdomains.
I have tried sharing the session table with no success.

what am i missing here ?

P.s - I have tried jfusion, it works, but i am not satisfied with the function as i dont see the point in using curl to submit form in subdomains.
I have used multisites SSO plugin from jms2win.It is basically designed to work on different domains than among sub domains. and it didn't work in my case too.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Share users and sessions can be easy, if you use your database to share user and session tables between sites you will be able to do with same domain, but this is not possible with diferent domains, and sometimes even subdomains. Why? Because browser cookies: you can only read cookies from same domain or a top level domain (i.g. read from sub.domain.com a cookie from domain.com).

At the end, you will need to do some workaround to solve this limitation. This is why you will need to use some external plugin, (like these you mention), or use some similar strategy to solve the cookie problem.

This is not about Joomla in special, but about how browsers works.

Comment: when i specify the cookie domain in every joomla instance, they do sync the session cookie.I was able to verify this with firebug.The reason for it to not work is the session token. Joomla forms generate and check these session token when you login. When i login to the master site it stores a token in the session, even though the slave site has access to the same session in the database, the token in the session and the token generated by the slave site form differs. Due to this the session expires. The only way to fix this is to get the tokens synchronise. But i could not get them to sync.

Comment: So you are doing something wrong in sincronization of session. If your sites share cookies (no domain problems) and you use some Joomla plugin or just create views for all user/session related tables from slaves sites to master site, this answer will work fine.