# Connect Joomla and Java App

Tags: java, sql, joomla

currently we are developing a JAVA APP that runs on TOMCAT and uses POSTGREE SQL

And we have an introducting website (JOOMLA 2.5 based) that explains the app, and also have a register module, that runs on APACHE PHP, on a different server.

Our goal is that the clients enter direct to our website JOOMLA, register there and then they can go directly to the web-app.

Very like to www.tiendanube.com or shopify.

The java-app has a login as well as the joomla website.. We need to unify those process, we cannot find a form to achieve this.

The problem is also that Joomla cannot run in the same server as the web-app.

Is there any way to interconnect both the web-page and the app (which runs in differents server) to make then look as one ?

So we thinked that when the user register in the joomla it also has to be saved in the same POSTGREE SQL of the java app. Since the java app is running in a different server we cannot access postgree SQL of the java app

That can be a solution, still we are pretty sure it has to be a easy solution or a more powerful and better solution for this.

Also been the 2 services in differents servers, it seems that we are not able to mantain the same domain for both.

We will really appreciate some help

Thanks very much
Facundo

Answer (score 2):

You have at least two ways to do it.

- Use a **LDAP**, **GMail authentication** or equivalent. Easy, Joomla already have it
- Do in a manual way with "**Single Sign On across multiple domains**". Will have to undestand how session cookies works and avoid avoid some problens.

Please read my recent answer on [implementing SSO across subdomains in joomla](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16859427/implementing-sso-across-subdomains-in-joomla/16879729#16879729)